# Using RegExp to keep only uppercase letters in a string

Tags: regex, vba

I have a column of strings from which I want to extract the uppercase words then past in another column. The words are always in the beginning of the string. For example:

APPLE ORANGE_20 lbs_15 ------> APPLE ORANGE

BANANA_10 lbs_30 -----------------> BANANA

GRAPE MANGO 30lbs_o ----------> GRAPE MANGO

This is what I have so far but I am having a hard time setting the Pattern to get the output needed:

```
Sub ExtractUPPERCASE()


Dim re As Object, mc As Object
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim s As String
Dim wbdata As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wbdata = Workbooks("trial1")
Set wsData = wbdata.Worksheets("Final Data")

wsData.Activate
Set r = wsData.Range("D1", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "^\s*([A-Z\W]+\b)\W+([\w\s]+)"
   '.Pattern = "([^a-z]+|[^0-9]+|(?=.*[^\w_]))" I tried this pattern but it didn't get what i want 
End With

For Each c In r
    s = c.Text
    If re.test(s) = True Then
        Set mc = re.Execute(s)
            c(1, 13) = mc(0).submatches(0)
    End If
Next c

Range(r(1, 13), r(1, 13)).EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Does this pattern work for you: `[A-Z]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ExtractUPPERCASE()


Dim re As Object, mc As Object
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim s As String
Dim wbdata As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wbdata = Workbooks("trial1")
Set wsData = wbdata.Worksheets("Final Data")

wsData.Activate
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "[A-Z]+\s?[A-Z]+"
End With

For Each c In r
    s = c.Text
    If re.test(s) = True Then
        Set mc = re.Execute(s)
            c(1, 13) = mc.Item(0).Value
    End If
Next c

Range(r(1, 13), r(1, 13)).EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```